# Derivation of one form of Navier-Stokes equation using another form of it

Tags: vector-analysis, fluid-dynamics

There are two forms of Navier-Stokes equations, which are $$\frac{\partial (\rho \boldsymbol U)}{\partial t} + \boldsymbol U\cdot \nabla(\rho \boldsymbol U)  = \boldsymbol f$$
$$\frac{\partial (\rho \boldsymbol U)}{\partial t} +  \nabla \cdot (\rho \boldsymbol U \boldsymbol U)  = \boldsymbol f$$
I tried to go through the derivation to prove that both vector terms are equal but [this calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ejygc.jpg) is all I have reached.
This attempt is based on considering the scalar component of the velocity and trying and to observe how both equations will behave in addition to running from dealing with tensors, which is quite tedious.I know that both equations are two forms of Navier-Stokes, but my issue is more related to vector analysis. In other words, how did we change the second term of the equation from the first form in the first equation to the second form in the second equation.
I hope my inquiry is clear enough.

Comment: Please include your thoughts, attempts, and provide more specific details about why you are stuck.  (Note: "I'm clueless" does not address my requests).

Comment: Do you mean to use \cdot rather than a full stop?

Comment: @EverywhereDense yes I mean the dot product.

Comment: @amWhy I am sorry I did not include my attempts. I just assumed that my attempts were too messy to be included in my inquiry as they might cause confusion. But you are definitely right I should have included any attempts to help clarify the issue.

Comment: What is $U$? Is it supposed to be the stress tensor (in which case these equations are much more general than the NS equations) or you are dealing with inviscid flows?

Comment: @PierreCarre U is the velocity vector and f is the summation of force per unit volume. These equation include the viscosity effect

Comment: @MostafaZewail The viscosity effect comes from a term of order 2 in space, normally $-\mu \Delta U$, which does not appear in your equations. You are missing the divergence of the stress tensor which, in the case of Newtonian fluids, is $\nabla p -\mu \Delta U$.

Comment: @PierreCarre the term f encapsulates the viscosity effect and the pressure gradient as well

Comment: @MostafaZewail This is a very misleading way of presenting the equations. Normally $f$ stands just for external forces. I would suggest that, at least, you write $f(U)$ in the equations.

Answer (score 2):

The two are equal due to the **incompressibility constraint**, which requires $\nabla\cdot U = 0$. Under this, you have, by the Leibniz rule

$$ \nabla\cdot (\rho \color{red}{U} \color{green}{U}) = \color{red}{U}\cdot \nabla(\rho \color{green}{U}) + (\rho \color{green}{U}) \underbrace{\nabla\cdot \color{red}{U}}_{=0}$$

Comment: Thanks you so much for replying to me. Now what if we are dealing with a compressible fluid ? Does that mean that the two equations are identical if and only if the fluid is assumed to be incompressible ?

Comment: Without incompressibility the two equations are not the same. (Note that standard Navier-Stokes assumes incompressibility.)

Comment: I think I misunderstood the difference between cauchy momentum equation and Navier stokes equation. If I got it right, Cauchy momentum equation and Navier Stokes equation are the same only at incomperssibility assumption, otherwise, they are two different set of equations. I hope I got it right and thank you so much for taking the time to help me.